# SplashScreen opens very late. How to fix this issue in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

This is my SplashScreen code

I'm facing 2 issues

1. In SplashScreen is opening late after login
2. Some dDevice white/ black  screen is shown

How can i fix this issue?

```
enimport 'package:cms/Configs/app_constants.dart';
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 class Splashscreen extends StatefulWidget
 {
   @override
   _Splashscreen createState() => _Splashscreen();
  }

 class _Splashscreen extends State<Splashscreen> {
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IsSplashOnlySolidColor == true
    ? Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    body: Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          valueColor:
          AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue)),
    ))
    : Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
  body: Center(
      child: Image.asset(
        'assets/images/logo.png',
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: could you post your main() func - usually app start up time depends on what you are doing when initialising the app

Answer (score 0):

You are making a screen display once your app opens, but a splash screen is something you show to the user when the app is being loaded by the OS.

You are seeing a white/black screen because there is no splash screen to show while loading the app. The code you provided runs once the black/white screen is over i.e. the app has loaded.

Use this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash to create a native splash screen which replaces the white/black screen you are seeing.

Comment: Hi Brother Thanks for this suggestion but it is not working splashscreen open very late or black screen issue is stilll here how can i fix this splashScreen issue please help i provide here full code main.dart file and splashScreen code so look at this and after tell how can i fix this issue